# My second screen is being recognized as a TV despite being a proper computer monitor

Tags: imac, displayport, night-shift

I'm on an iMac 5K 2017 and I've connected my second screen, an Acer ProDesigner BM320, via a USB-C-to-MiniDP adapter.

According to the system information the monitor is being recognized as a TV which keeps it from being used with Night Shift.

Is there anything I can do to change that? Why is this the case in the first place? It is no TV, why is macOS configuring it like one? By the way, using another adapter to let's say HDMI didn't change anything if I remember correctly. And MiniDP is no connector which is being used on TVs.

Comment: It's showing up as a TV because the EDID information the monitor is sending to your Mac is telling saying its a TV.  What TV model is it coming back as?

Comment: This is the output from system information (in German, sorry):

BM320:
  Auflösung: 6016 x 3384
  UI sieht aus wie: 3008 x 1692 @ 60 Hz
  Framepuffertiefe: 30-Bit Farbe (ARGB2101010)
  Display-Seriennummer: T7LEE0018511
  Synchronisierung: Aus
  Eingeschaltet: Ja
  Rotation: Unterstützt
  Helligkeit automatisch anpassen: Nein
  Verbindungstyp: DisplayPort
  Fernseher: Ja

Comment: I found this a minute ago. I gonna give it a try later that day: https://github.com/Akemi/macOS-edid-modification

Comment: I was able to extract the EDID information from that file but there's no attribute (at least none that I could find) regarding the device typ.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem, the monitor is still being recognized as a TV, forcing it to RGB (which it was before already AFAIK) didn't change anything.